# Jaws screen reader IE 11 select tag issue

Tags: internet-explorer-11, jaws-screen-reader

I have some issues with IE 11 and Jaws. Please take a look at the example below.

**Simplified code example:**

```
<input type="text" />
<span role="alert" aria-live="assertive" id="err"></span>
<select id="colours">
  <option value="White">White invalid</option>
  <option value="Green">Green invalid</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>


var i = 0;
$('#colours').on('keyup', function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex') < 2) {
        $('#err').html('an error has occurred ' + i++);
    }
    else {
        $('#err').html('');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/obwapffq/2/

Basically, I am validating the selected element in a dropdown list (in the example 'white' and 'green' values are invalid). I am only using the keyboard's up and down buttons to change the selected value. If an invalid option is selected, I update the content of a span element with the appropriate error message. The span element has role="alert" and aria-live="assertive". I have 2 issues:

1. If the selected option is invalid, the error message is read out, but the selected option is not read out and so the user does not know what option is invalid i.e. what option caused that error.
2. Sometimes even the valid options are not read out. This mostly happens with the first valid option in the list i.e. in the example 'Red'

This is working 100% correct with NVDA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please add aria-label="yourOptionText" attribute to your option tag.
for e.g. aria-label="White Invalid".
Hope this will help.